# Covergence/ divergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I came across a problem in a Math test I had to take a few days ago. I wasn't able to solve it. I am reconstructing the problem from what I've scribbled in my attempt to solve the problem. Please forgive me if the question isn't specific.

**Question:**

Let $b_n=(-1)^n \cdot n! \cdot\sin(a) \cdot\sin(a/2) \cdot\sin(a/3) \cdot \ldots \cdot\sin(a/n)$. For what what values of $a$ does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converge absolutely? For what what values of $a$ does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converge conditionally? For what what values of $a$ does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ diverge?
The question was in MCQ format in the test. The options were of the type "$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges absolutely/conditionally/diverges for $a=(something)$".

So, I want to investigate the behavior of the series for different values of $a$.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What ways of analysing convergence of series have you covered?  For example, ratio test?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the fact that $|\sin t| \leq |t|$, you have that

$$\left|n! \prod_{i=1}^n \sin\frac ai \right|\leq |a|^n$$

So, if $|a|<1$ your series is bounded by a series of the form $\sum (-1)^n b_n$ with $b_n \to 0$. Does this ring a bell?